# Wheel Tire Height Change: 27Plus to 29

Tags: tire, 29er, 27-inch

All,

I have a 2017 Scott Spark 720. It has 27.5 Plus Tires on it 2.8 maxis recon which I run at 16/18 psi (amazing traction).

I have been getting a lot of pedal strikes (In rocky/rooted turns, mild but annoying and throwing me off line) and have been considering purchasing a 29 inch wheel set to put 2.6 tires on it. I estimate that I would be running closer to 25 psi in them.

Approximately, how much would this increase my BB height by? I think if I could get 1-3 cm increase the pedal strikes would pretty much disappear.

Comment: Do you ride with flat pedals?  Might be worth exploring MTB cleats and shoes and clipless pedals.  They're thinner and shorter, effectively harder to ground strike in the turns

Comment: I ride shimano spd cleats and small platform pedals. Its typically my shoe that contacts.

Comment: Your other option is to learn when to pedal and when to coast.   For MTBs, turning with your outer-pedal down means the bars would strike the ground before the raised inner pedal.   Sharper turns should be coasted with inside pedal raised.

Comment: Good point but I like to go fast and these turns are very sharp. I could pedal them on my last bike. I just think I am riding a bit lower on this one.

Comment: How’s long are your cranks? I’m wondering if shorter cranks are an option. What about your 29er crank length?

Comment: 170mm cranks on the bike

Comment: Have you tried increasing sir pressure in shock and fork? Play around and see if there a sweat spot between a stiffer setup and avoiding pedal strike. How long since you switched bikes - from experience it takes a while to 'tune in' to  a lower BB.

Comment: About 3 months now. Just feeling good with tuned it up for my best traction and speed. I'd rather not stiffen it up more. I can lock it out fully with the twin loc on the handle bar but then I get a different type of beating

Comment: @Criggie you’re so skilled at gently telling people they’re doing it wrong lol, I love it. Learning the habit of keeping that inside pedal up costs nothing and removes the problem on any bike.

Comment: Off topic: I managed to pedal strike somehow pulling out of a junction (flats on a road bike don’t ask) and it literally threw me over the handlebars. So thankful the following car was paying attention, but i must have looked very strange!

Comment: @Swifty thanks - there's nothing gained by being obnoxious.  I didn't figure this out, someone told/taught me how to do it better.

Comment: @swifty Another technique that could mitigate the impact of a pedal strike is to keep the lower pedal further back, behind the BB axle.  So if it contacts the ground it will be swept back and not act as a lever to lift the rear wheel off the ground, which is probably what happened to you - can only have two points of contact with the ground (tyres) and adding a third point (pedal) will lift the rear, leading to a rear wheel slide and fall while turning.  Anyway this is getting OT so move to [chat]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between 622mm rims on 29” wheels and 584mm on 27.5” wheels is only 19mm - about 3/4 if an inch. If you run a narrower tire the rim plus tire diameter different is even less.

In general bike frames do not have clearance for larger wheels so this may not even be possible.

Note that larger wheels will also change your steering geometry.

Comment: If I add the same height in the back and front steering geometry should be the same correct.

Comment: Steering angle will be kept the same but trail increases with larger wheels

Comment: Thats a good point but not much since 27plus tires are only about 1/4" shorter than my other 29er. I am really thinking I will get most benefit from less squat of the tire.

Comment: If you have a 29er then at least you can try the frame clearance before you buy new wheels!

Comment: Great idea. My 29er is qr and the New bike is boost but just holding the 29" wheel in place and measuring my tire squat when seated on both bikes should give me a good idea of what benefits could be had.

Answer (score 3):

I have a 2017 Yeti SB5+. I too was running anywhere from 14-18 PSI when I first started riding it and I was getting a lot of pedal strikes, something I hadn't even thought of on other bikes. When I started riding on much faster downhill terrain the tire was wandering a lot and was very unstable. I swapped out my 2.8 Rekon on the front for a DHF and started running 20-23 PSI (front and rear, usually a bit less in the front). Not only did the ride become significantly more stable and planted at speed, but I noticed a huge reduction in pedal strikes with an almost negligible reduction in traction. The bike still feels great and provides all of the benefits of a plus sized platform, but is much more stable and rider friendly.

So long story short, try increasing your tire pressure.

Comment: I will give this a try on my next ride